# How does absolute difference 'N' works? Explanation needed

Tags: java, int

I am doing java exercise in coding bat and came across the following question. Honestly, I could not figure out the question and looked for the solution. Can you guys please explain me the below code and how the logic works?

Question:

Given an int n, return the absolute difference between n and 21, except return double the absolute difference if n is over 21.

diff21(19) → 2
diff21(10) → 11
diff21(21) → 0

Solution code. Why do we need to **subtract** the **N** from 21?

```
public int diff21(int n) {
  if (n <= 21) {
    return 21 - n;
  } else {
    return (n - 21) * 2;
  }
}
```

Comment: I’m not sure what you’re asking. You need to return the absolute difference. You can use pencil and paper to run through the two conditions (also try negative values). You subtract n so you can find the difference; that’s what subtraction is.

Comment: Because your `if` establishes that `n` is less than or equal to `21`. Thus the absolute difference must be `21 - n` (since `n` is in the range `Integer.MIN_VALUE <= n <= 21`)

Answer (score 1):

```
If n > 21:
  # as quoted: "double the absolute difference"
else:
  # return just the absolute difference
```

An absolute number is always positive (a real number).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value

Comment: In case it wasn't absolutely (no pun intended...) clear before, "absolute difference" == "absolute value of the difference".

Answer (score 1):

You have to subtract N from 21 because absolute value is the positive difference between 2 numbers. `n-21` is invalid because if n is larger than 21, the program will just return double `n`, so you know that `n` should never be larger than 21. Therefore, `n-21` would always return a negative value, which shouldn't happen because the exercise requires absolute value, which is always positive.

Answer (score 1):

To find the difference between two numbers is to find how far apart the two numbers are from eachother.

For example the difference between 1 and 7 is 6, which can be found by doing 7-1. You have to subtract the larger value from the smaller value in order to find the difference, otherwise you will end up with an incorrect number.

In your example if the code `if(n<=21)` returns `true` then the value of `n` will be less than or equal to 21 which means that it is safe to do `21-n`.

If you did not use the if-else statement and instead your code only had `return 21-n;` then if the value of `n` was larger than 21, a negative number would be returned which would be incorrect.

Answer (score -2):

#Coding bat problem warmup-1 diff21

**Question:** Given an int n, return the absolute difference between n and 21, except return double the absolute difference if n is over 21.

**Solution:**

```
def diff21(n):
  if n > 21:
    return 2*abs(21 - n)
  else:
    return abs(21 - n)
```

Comment: Not answering the question, just re-posting same info as the OP.